# Variável dentro do Select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, input

Em meu sistema Web eu tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT round(SUM(peso),3) FROM mov02s WHERE modal = ('Carreta simples') AND data = ('2018-05-16')
```

Eu gostaria de usar uma variável no lugar de '2018-05-16'. O usuário que vai escolher a data.

Pensei em fazer um input do tipo date com javascript:

```
<input type="date" id="myDate" value="2018-06-26" />
```

Porém ainda não consegui evoluir. Não consegui a variável.

Comment: Qual linguagem está usando para backend? PHP? Não tem essa informação nem na tag, nem na pergunta.

Comment: Sim deve ter um input, que depois será passado para o teu código, dentro do seu código terá uma variável que ira receber essa data, que só então vai adicionar a sua consulta.. Qual a linguagem de programação que está utilizando? O que mais tem desenvolvido? Adicione outros códigos.

Comment: Se for php e so da um prepare, depois passa a variável e depois executa. Como você envia essa data, pode ser por post ou por javascript.

Comment: O linguagem usada é php. Estou usando o framework Laravel

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o trecho do seu controller que recebe a submissão do formulário com o input mydate para que possamos ajudar melhor. Existem formas diferentes de fazer, se você mostrar o caminho que está tomando facilitará para dar uma sugestão de código.